# ¿Cómo rellenar un select mediante un array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un pequeño problema: no sé cómo mostrar los datos que están dentro de mis cajas de texto,  dentro de mi select, ya que quiero que mediante mi función *guardar*, se almacenen dentro del select utilizando un array.

Las líneas de código que llevo hasta el momento:

```js
function guardar {
  var select = document.getElementById('lista');
  var latitud = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cordenada1').value);
  var longitud = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cordenada2').value);
  var numero = new numero[100];
  for (var i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(numero[i], i);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="lista">
</select>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código HTML ligado al código Javascript que presentas y dinos cuál es el problema o error en sí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios problemas (y malas prácticas) en tu código. Intento enumerarlos:

- Para crear un valor equivalente a `100`, esto no tiene sentido: `var numero=new numero[100];`, basta con esto: `var numero=100;`
- En consecuencia, el bucle se escribirá así: `for(var i=0; i<numero;i++){`
- Es una mala práctica modificar elementos del DOM en bucles, esto tiene su coste. Es mejor construir una cadena dentro del bucle y modificar el elemento una sola vez, fuera del bucle.

```js
guardar();

function guardar() {
  var select = document.getElementById('lista');
  //var latitud=parseFloat(document.getElementById('cordenada1').value);
  //var //longitud=parseFloat(document.getElementById('cordenada2').value);
  var numero = 100;
  /*Variable para concatenar los option*/
  var mOptions = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
    mOptions += `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`;
  }
  /*Modificamos el select una vez, no 100 veces*/
  select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', mOptions);
}
```

```html
<select id="lista">
</select>
```

Aquí he usado [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) que nos permite insertar los `option` en un lugar determinado del elemento, en este caso, hemos indicado `beforeend`, para que los inserte *antes del fin*.